# Using GregorianCalendar with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, simpledateformat, illegalargumentexception, gregorian-calendar

So, I've been racking my brain over this (should-be) simple exercise to make the program turn a date string into a `GregorianCalendar` object, format it, and return it again as a string when it's done.

This is the last little bit of a program that takes in a chuck of text from a file, breaks it down into individual records, then breaks the records into individual pieces of data and assigns them to a person object.

I've checked the code in multiple places and the code does exactly what it's supposed to be doing up until I call the format function, which throws an `IllegalArgumentException`. The `GergorianCalendar` object is assigned the values it is supposed to be assigned (though printing it is, again, a whole other story as seen below…), yet the format will not accept the object for formatting.

Unfortunately, the instructor wasn't too sure of how to use the `GregorianCalendar` and `SimpleDateFormat` (yet assigned us to work with them) and said: "Just Google it…" I tried, and nothing I've found has helped.

The code I have so far is:

```
public class DateUtil {

    public static GregorianCalendar convertFromDMY(String dd_mm_yy) throws ParseException{

        // this actually works, got rid of the original code idea
        String[] splitDate = dd_mm_yy.split("-");
        int days = Integer.parseInt(splitDate[0]);
        int month = Integer.parseInt(splitDate[1]);
        int year = Integer.parseInt(splitDate[2]);

        // Dates are going in right, checked in print statement,
        // but the object is not getting formatted…
        GregorianCalendar dateConverted = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, days);
        format(dateConverted);
        return dateConverted;
    }

    public static String format(GregorianCalendar date){

        SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        String dateFormatted = fmt.format(date);
        return dateFormatted;
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object >as a Date

    at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:281)
    at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:140)
    at lab2.DateUtil.format(DateUtil.java:26) 
    at lab2.DateUtil.convertFromDMY(DateUtil.java:19)
    at lab2.Lab2.createStudent(Lab2.java:75)
    at lab2.Lab2.main(Lab2.java:34)
```

And another thing, am I even using the `GregorianCalendar` right?? When I print out that object's value (should be getting a date, right?) I get this:

> java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=false,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Vancouver",offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=189,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/Vancouver,offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=?,YEAR=1985,MONTH=4,WEEK_OF_YEAR=?,WEEK_OF_MONTH=?,DAY_OF_MONTH=22,DAY_OF_YEAR=?,DAY_OF_WEEK=?,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=?,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=?,ZONE_OFFSET=?,DST_OFFSET=?]

The year, month and day_of_month values are all correct as they are the numbers I passed into the creation of it.

Thoughts, suggestions, am I even close?

**Edit**

Original issues cleared up (thank you assylias!), but I still can't print properly because the two functions aren't linked and the requirements are to have a `GregorianCalendar` date value printed out from the person object (as birthdate is a `GregorianCalendar`).

Updated code:

```
public class DateUtil {

    static SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

    public static GregorianCalendar convertFromDMY(String dd_mm_yy) throws ParseException{

        // this actually works, got rid of the original code idea
        String[] splitDate = dd_mm_yy.split("-");
        int days = Integer.parseInt(splitDate[0]);
        int month = (Integer.parseInt(splitDate[1]) - 1);
        int year = Integer.parseInt(splitDate[2]);

        // dates go in properly
        GregorianCalendar dateConverted = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, days);
        String finalDate = format(dateConverted);
        return ;
    }

    public static String format(GregorianCalendar date) throws ParseException{

       fmt.setCalendar(date);
        String dateFormatted = fmt.format(date.getTime());
        System.out.println(dateFormatted);
        return dateFormatted;
    }

}
```

**Last edit**

OK, so it seems that I'm an idiot and DIDN'T need to link the two `DateUtil` functions together, but use them in tandem. First, convert the birthdate to a `GregorianCalendar` and store it in the person object. Then, in the print statement, just simply tell the program to format that date as it's being printed. Problem was solved. All works according to specifications now, and I feel that much stupider because I was flailing like a fish out of water for the last day or so with the `DateUtil` class, trying to get them to work at the same time.

Thanks for the help all on getting the date go in properly!

Comment: FYI, to format code on StackOverflow, start a line with 4 (or more) spaces. Use `>` only for non-code quotes.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat.format()` method takes a `Date` as a parameter. You can get a `Date` from a `Calendar` by calling its `getTime()` method:

```
public static String format(GregorianCalendar calendar) {
    SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    fmt.setCalendar(calendar);
    String dateFormatted = fmt.format(calendar.getTime());

    return dateFormatted;
}
```

Also note that the months start at 0, so you probably meant:

```
int month = Integer.parseInt(splitDate[1]) - 1;
```

Comment: You might also want to *set* the calendar in the `SimpleDateFormat`, so that it knows to use that rather than a different calendar system.

Comment: lol i thought there was something to date, but i fooled around with it for a while and couldn't make it work so i gave up on it =P

i'll report back in a few

Comment: ok yeah so that fixed the error, i feel like an idiot for not distinguishing between a date and a calendar >< only issue is that when printing the date out now i still get that long line for GergorianCalendar data rather than an actual date

Comment: and i fixed that by playing around with the print statement, the toString() was not right as pointed out by JB Nizet below. thanks all!

Comment: Not sure what changes you have made, but in the code of your question this statement: `format(dateConverted);` does nothing (i.e. your code would do exactly the same thing if you removed that line).

Comment: well i got it printing out the year, month or day of each individual person object lol but not all at the same time so ALMOST. so close yet so far lol

Comment: when i print of the string in the format function it works like a charm, but getting the two functions to work together is not happening for me right now =[ the guidelines for this exercise are so vague

Comment: @RejectionHurts That's what my previous comment was about. The `format` method creates a formatted string which you never use in the `convertFromDMY` method. You should have something like `String formattedDate = format(dateConverted);` in `convertFromDMY` for example.

Comment: "SimpleDateFormat#format method takes a Date as a parameter" Sorry, you are wrong. It takes Object. But if the object is not considered good, it throws IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: yeah, i see what you mean, it was just sitting there. the updated code is up there now, I'm not sure what to return since the issue is gonna be the same if i return a gregoriancalendar. it'll print out that long line again, not the actual date i'm getting from the string =/

Answer (score 6):

Why such complications?

```
public static GregorianCalendar convertFromDMY(String dd_mm_yy) throws ParseException 
{
    SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    Date date = fmt.parse(dd_mm_yy);
    GregorianCalendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    return cal;
}
```

Comment: it was a requirement that there have to be those 2 functions =/ nothing is ever simple lol

Comment: Well you can split this into 2 **methods** (not functions) if you wish :)

Comment: the line about the return statement provides an error of 
"cannot convert from void to GregorianCalendar"

Comment: @RejectionHurts: I fixed the code. You need to split it on two lines.

Answer (score 3):

A `SimpleDateFormat`, as its name indicates, formats `Date`s. Not a `Calendar`. So, if you want to format a `GregorianCalendar` using a `SimpleDateFormat`, you must convert the `Calendar` to a `Date` first:

```
dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
```

And what you see printed is the `toString()` representation of the calendar. It's intended usage is debugging. It's not intended to be used to display a date in a GUI. For that, use a (`Simple`)`DateFormat`.

Finally, to convert from a `String` to a `Date`, you should also use a (`Simple`)`DateFormat` (its `parse()` method), rather than splitting the `String` as you're doing. This will give you a `Date` object, and you can create a `Calendar` from the `Date` by instanciating it (`Calendar.getInstance()`) and setting its time (`calendar.setTime()`).

My advice would be: Googling is not the solution here. Reading the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) is what you need to do.

Answer (score 2):

1. You are putting there a two-digits year. The first century. And the Gregorian calendar started in the 16th century. I think you should add 2000 to the year.
2. Month in the function `new GregorianCalendar(year, month, days)` is 0-based. Subtract 1 from the month there.
3. Change the body of the second function as follows:

   ```
       String dateFormatted = null;
       SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
       try {
           dateFormatted = fmt.format(date);
       }
       catch ( IllegalArgumentException e){
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
       return dateFormatted;
   ```

After debugging, you'll see that simply `GregorianCalendar` can't be an argument of the `fmt.format();`.

Really, nobody needs `GregorianCalendar` as output, even you are told to return "a string".

Change the header of your format function to

```
public static String format(final Date date)
```

and make the appropriate changes. `fmt.format()` will take the `Date` object gladly.

4. Always after an unexpected exception arises, catch it yourself, don't allow the Java machine to do it. This way, you'll understand the problem.

Comment: unfortunately i can't make the last change you suggested as it states those are the functions to use, can't change them =/ i did fix the -1 already, totally forgot that, the year is not a problem it seems, and the body of my format function works properly now that assylias' changes have been implemented =P i added a print statement into the format function just to see, and they print out according to the exercise requirements. ill update the above code

Comment: The year is a problem - there was no gregorian calendar in the first century AC. Correct function will check the input for the date being after gregorian calendar was firstly set.

Comment: Of course, you can make transfer GregorianCalendar.getTime() inside the function, too. For example, fmt.format(date.getTime()). But it is also extremely bad to name GregorianCalendar variable as Date variable. Names should sit with their types.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse(
    "23-Mar-2017" ,
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-uuuu" , Locale.US ) 
)
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The Question and other Answers are now outdated, using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

## Using java.time

You seem to be dealing with date-only values. So do not use a date-time class. Instead use `LocalDate`. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

Specify a [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine (a) the human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such, and (b) the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

Parse a string.

```
String input = "23-Mar-2017" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-uuuu" , Locale.US ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f );
```

Generate a string.

```
String output = ld.format( f );
```

If you were given numbers rather than text for the year, month, and day-of-month, use `LocalDate.of`.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2017 , 3 , 23 );  // ( year , month 1-12 , day-of-month )
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/mMBDbx).

> input: 23-Mar-2017
>
> ld.toString(): 2017-03-23
>
> output: 23-Mar-2017

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Using a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings nor java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).