# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad class: class java.util.GregorianCalendar

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar, gregorian-calendar

I received this exception while using `GregorianCalendar`

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad class: class java.util.GregorianCalendar`

Who know how to fix,

Please help me.

p/s : I used the following code :

```
Calendar someDate = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        someDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -7);
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(someDate);
```

**UPDATED** I should be use this line to achieve the date time :

`String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(someDate.getTime());`

Comment: If using eclipse: remove your imports, then do ctrl+Shift+O

Comment: huh? don't understand your case clearly. But after do thing as u said. still can not fix issu

Comment: Same What i want to ask :P

Comment: Yeah, many people need it :p

Answer (score 97, accepted):

A Calendar can't be directly formatted, you need to get the Date from the Calendar, like this:

```
String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(someDate.getTime());
```

Comment: Actually it's not so good to call a method like this, signature:
`public final Date getTime()` (I expect get date method which will return time :)

Comment: @xwild What do you mean?

Comment: I mean calendar methods naming are not so good, getTime should return Time (i.e. 12:00), getDate shoud return Date (i.e. 2016-01-01), but now in java `getTime()` returns a `Date` instance.

Comment: `Calendar` is not a subclass of `Date`. Why does this compile on Android?

Comment: @peter: `Calendar.getTime()` retrieves the `Calendar` as a `Date`.

Comment: @wvdz I mean `SimpleDateFormat::format(Calendar)`. It compiled on my Android app but then it threw a  a runtime exception

Comment: @peter. `SimpleDateFormat` extends `Format` which has `format(Object)`.

Answer (score 2):

As one of the answers here: [Using GregorianCalendar with SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829942/using-gregoriancalendar-with-simpledateformat) says "A SimpleDateFormat, as its name indicates, formats Dates."

So, try this:

```
String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(someDate.getDate());
```

Comment: `someDate.getTime()` will be return `Date`, not `someDate.getDate()`