# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad class: class java.lang.String

Tags: java, android, string, date, parsing

I read about the problem but I can't find where is my mistake. I have dates in my Datebase and when I retrieve them and try to compare them with the current date this error comes in the logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
       Process: com.example.hpdemon.diploma, PID: 9879
       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.hpdemon.diploma.BroadcastManager: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad class: class java.lang.String
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2417)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:138)
           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1275)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5034)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:731)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:565)
           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad class: class java.lang.String
           at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:296)
           at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:93)
           at com.example.hpdemon.diploma.BroadcastManager.onReceive(BroadcastManager.java:51)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2410)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:138) 
           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1275) 
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5034) 
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

The error comes on this line `deadline = new Date(deadline.getTime() - 604800000L);` My code is:

```
        Users_Database db = new Users_Database(context);
        String currentUsrname = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString("USRNFORBROADCAST", "NothingFound");
        List<String> dates=db.getAllDates(db.findID(currentUsrname));
        String dateIns = "";
        String dateVin = "";
        String dateTax = "";
        // int tyres;
        dateIns=(dates.get(0));
        dateVin=(dates.get(1));
        dateTax=(dates.get(2));
        dateIns = dateIns.replaceAll("\n", "");

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();//текуща дата
        Date todayDate = c.getTime();
        Date deadline=c.getTime();

        try {
            todayDate = sdf.parse(sdf.format(todayDate.getTime()));
            deadline = sdf.parse(sdf.format(dateIns));
            deadline = new Date(deadline.getTime() - 604800000L);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (todayDate.before(deadline) /*&& hour.equals(yourHour)*/) {
            Intent it = new Intent(context, BootServices.class);
            createNotification(context, it, "I Love My Car", "Краен срок!", "Изтичащ преглед");
            context.startService(it);
        }
```

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace please?

Comment: it is beacuse it expect date or time and you ae passing the String

Comment: @Sam I can't understand where I'm wrong

Comment: error at parse function.

Comment: have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24041513/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-bad-class-class-java-util-gregoriancalendar/24041714

Comment: The issue is here (I think): `sdf.format(dateIns)`. You are trying to format something that is already a string. It doesn’t make sense to do, and a `SimpleDateFormat` cannot do it. Therefore it throws the exception. You would have preferred a compile time error message, but since `format` is declared to accept `Object`, you don’t get that.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: @OleV.V.
Thank you! The problem was sdf.format(dateIns). Because dateIns was a String, after I changed it to Date it works!

Comment: Great that you solved it. And great that you want to share the solution. Please do that in an answer, not by modifying the question. It all makes better sense that way. You may also accept your own answer (after a quarantine period) so that it will be clear for all that a solution has been found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### java.time

It’s not perfectly clear from the question, but I think you were trying to do something like the following:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");

    List<String> dates = Arrays.asList("31/05/2018", "19/06/2018", "01/07/2018");
    String dateIns = dates.get(0);
    dateIns = dateIns.replaceAll("\n", "");

    LocalDate todayDate = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Pacific/Rarotonga"));
    LocalDate deadline = LocalDate.parse(dateIns, dateFormatter).minusWeeks(1);
    if (todayDate.isBefore(deadline)) {
        System.out.println("I Love My Car. Краен срок! Изтичащ преглед.");
    }
```

Running this snippet just now, since 19th May is strictly before 24th May, it printed

> I Love My Car. Краен срок! Изтичащ преглед.

Please substitute your desired time zone if it didn’t happen to be Pacific/Rarotonga.

I am using and recommending `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. A `LocalDate` is a date without time of day and seems just right for your needs. And the entire `java.time` is so much nicer to work with than `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`, which are long outdated, and `SimpleDateFormat` in particular notoriously troublesome.

If you are using at least Java 8 or Android API level 26 or higher, you should make sure you’ve got a JDBC 4.2 compliant driver and then retrieve `LocalDate` objects rather than strings from your database. In this way you are free from any parsing of the strings in your code, it is not only easier, it is also less error-prone.

### What went wrong in your code?

I believe the issue is in this line:

```
    deadline = sdf.parse(sdf.format(dateIns));
```

Here `dateIns` is a `String`. It doesn’t make sense to format something that is already a string, and `SimpleDateFormat` cannot do that and therefore throws the exception you got. You would have preferred and maybe expected a compile-time error message when passing the wrong type to the `format` method. `SimpleDateFormat` inherits a `format(Date)` method from `DateFormat` but also a `format(Object)` method from `Format`. So with the `String` the latter is called, and the compiler has no way of telling that anything is wrong.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, `java.time` works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least Java **6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26, I’m told) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You do not provide enough info for a precise Answer. So here are some pointers.

You are using terrible old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

- `Instant` replaced `Date`
- `ZonedDateTime` replaced `Calendar`
- `DateTimeFormatter` replaced `SimpleDateFormat`

If you must inter-operate with old code not yet updated for *java.time*, you can convert back and forth by calling new conversion methods added to the old classes.

You are using dumb strings where you should be using smart objects. As of JDBC 4.2, you can directly exchange *java.time* objects with your database.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

An `Instant` is always in UTC. To get a date, you must specify a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ; 
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Extract a date-only value, apparently your goal.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

Compare by calling `isBefore` and `isAfter`.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. This is the first android app I'm creating. So I'll keep in mind your advice.