# How can I format a GregorianCalendar

Tags: java, date, format, date-formatting, gregorian-calendar

I have a [`GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) object. How do I get a formatted string?

The line `System.out.print("End of rental: " + endDate);` produces the following really long calendar. How can I format this down to dd/mm/yyyy?

```
End of rental: java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1495050625200,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/London",offset=0,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=242,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/London,offset=0,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2017,MONTH=4,WEEK_OF_YEAR=20,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=17,DAY_OF_YEAR=137,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=1,HOUR=8,HOUR_OF_DAY=20,MINUTE=50,SECOND=25,MILLISECOND=200,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=3600000]
```

Comment: you should check the documentation for `java.util.GregorianCalendar`

Comment: There must be 50 Q/A on date formatting on this site. But check [`DateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) for example.

Comment: @KevinO Actually, I looked for a duplicate Question but could not find one specifically asking how to format a `GregorianCalendar`. So I wrote an Answer. If you can find a duplicate, please mark this Question as a duplicate and I will vote to close along with you.

Comment: @BasilBourque, with all due respect, [Using GregorianCalendar with SimpleDateFormat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829942/using-gregoriancalendar-with-simpledateformat) for example. But whether one uses `SimpleDateFormat`or `DateTimeFormatter`, the basic question is still about formatting a date, which is asked/answer all the time. Nonetheless, your answer is specific to this question. It is the larger problem of the OP, in all likelihood, googling for the *specifics* without understanding the general approach. Note: I'm not a DV.

Comment: @KevinO (A) [That Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10829942/642706) is too over-wrought to be considered a duplicate of the very simple question of “I have a GregorianCalendar object, how do I get a formatted string?”. So this Questions still stands as a valid and useful one to keep. I have closed many Questions as duplicates, but only where clear-cut. I am annoyed by the down-votes here by people who have not bothered to cite a duplicate. Yes, it *seemed* like a dup to me too until I bothered to look and found none. (B) What is a “DV” - oh, I get it, "Down-Voter"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using GregorianCalendar with SimpleDateFormat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829942/using-gregoriancalendar-with-simpledateformat)

Comment: @Matthias [That Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10829942/642706) is not a duplicate. That question is mainly about parsing a string into a `GregorianCalendar` object whereas **this Question starts with a `GregorianCalendar` object in hand**.  To quote: “turn a date string into a GregorianCalendar object”, “ takes in a chuck of text from a file, breaks it down”, “`convertFromDMY`”.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
endDate.toZonedDateTime()
       .format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) )
```

> 23/01/2017

## Details

Convert from the troublesome legacy class of `GregorianCalendar`  to the modern java.time class of [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). Call [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#toString--) to generate text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
endDate.toZonedDateTime().toString()
```

Get something like this:

> 2017-01-23T12:34:56.789-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]

For just your date, use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). [Specify](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-) your custom formatting pattern.

```
endDate.toZonedDateTime()
       .format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) )
```

> 23/01/2017

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Dear Down-Voter: Please leave a criticism along with your vote.

Comment: Hey, I have been playing with `java.time` for long now, had not discovered this conversion yet, between `GregorianCalendar` and `ZonedDateTime`. It’s a natural and good thing to have since those classes match well on intended use. The opposite conversion exists as `GregorianCalendar.from(ZonedDateTime)`. Thanks for the news, no matter if it’s old news.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes, this conversion avenue is not obvious because the methods live only on the concrete `GregorianCalendar` class but *not* on the commonly-used `Calendar` abstract class. If you have a `Calendar` object in hand you must test with `instanceOf` to verify it is actually a `GregorianCalendar`, cast it, then call the conversion method.

Answer (score 2):

@Basil Bourque’s answer is highly recommended. I’d just like to supplement it with the answer for Java 6 and 7 (so please ignore if you are on Java 8 or later). Also if you can avoid the `Calendar` class completely, which is best, you should use that other answer. In the following I am assuming that you cannot avoid getting a `Calendar` object from some legacy API that you cannot change or don’t want to change just now.

### java.time and ThreeTen Backport

I am taking my example from a duplicate question, *How to convert a Calendar object to date format that looks like this* (link at the bottom). The desired format there was given as

```
7/23/2019 11:02:11 AM
```

Which we can obtain in the following way. First we instantiate a formatter:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/u h:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Then we use it like this

```
    Calendar cal = getCalendarFromLegacyApi();

    ZonedDateTime zdt = DateTimeUtils.toZonedDateTime(cal);
    String howItShouldLook = zdt.format(formatter);
    System.out.println(howItShouldLook);
```

Output in this example is the desired:

> 7/23/2019 11:02:11 AM

### Question: Can I use java.time on Java 7?

Yes, java.time works nicely Java 7. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTen Backport API documentation (Javadoc)](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/index.html)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- The duplicate question [How to convert a Calendar object to date format that looks like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57163819/how-to-convert-a-calendar-object-to-date-format-that-looks-like-this) that was the occasion for providing this answer.